# Precompiled preamble causing issues with ntheorem

Tags: pdftex, theorems, ntheorem, mylatexformat

Whenever I compiled a file, it always took about 30 seconds, so I read up on using mylatexformat to precompile my packages. I have figured out how to do so and have stored my fmt file as /home/username/.texlive/texmf-config/web2c/pdftex/packages.fmt so that it is available globally. Here is the contents of my format file:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{import}
\let\clipbox\relax
\usepackage[document,bottom]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots}
\usepackage{bm}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween,polar}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles,arrows,3d,backgrounds,arrows.meta,calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{listings}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[amsthm]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\savesymbol{degree}
\usepackage{stmaryrd} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

I compile this with `pdflatex -ini -interaction=nonstopmode -save-size=20000 -stack-size=2000 -jobname="packages" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx "packages.tex"`. But when I run pdflatex on a file, it list the packages that are preloaded. However, the following packages are not loaded from my initial file:

```
listings
ntheorem
pdfpages
pst-eucl
degree
subfig
xspace
xpatch
```

My problem occurs when loading my theorems as I get this output:

```
(/home/anthanor2/texmf/tex/latex/ntheorem/ntheorem.sty
Style `ntheorem', Version 1.33 <2011/08/15>

! Package ntheorem Error: Theorem style plain already defined.

See the ntheorem package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.524 ...rfont ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
```

I had a problem with xpatch as well but fixed it by using `\RequirePackage{xpatch}`, however this does not work for ntheorem and I have no idea why. I have tried running the same code without a fmt file (as I normally would), and did not get these errors. Any ideas? Let me know if more information is needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thirty seconds? That's really unusual.

Comment: In my experiment those packages are loaded (those that are called, I mean). Can you show the log from the run producing the format?

Comment: I know, 95% of that time is spent loading packages which is odd. Do you have any advice on how to make it faster/ figure out what the problem is?

Comment: I just realized I made a stupid mistake as I was working on this late last night. When I was experimenting with mylatexfmt, I left another packages.fmt in my project directory so that's what screwed it up. Thanks so much for your help! If you have any suggestions for my speed though I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments by OP.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Sorry, I didn't mark this as resolved. I'm just curious, why was my question marked as off topic? I just want to make sure the quality of any future post are of good quality.

Comment: @JoshuaA There is no problem, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8775.