# Precompiled preamble causing new errors with ntheorem

Tags: pdftex, ntheorem, format-files, logging, mylatexformat

I'll start off by noting that I already made a post yesterday with a similar title and want to say that this is a new problem.  [Here's the link to my previous post if it helps provide any context.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623152/precompiled-preamble-causing-issues-with-ntheorem) I have a precompiled preamble of packages:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{import}
\let\clipbox\relax
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[document,bottom]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
%\savesymbol{degree}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween,polar}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles,arrows,3d,backgrounds,arrows.meta,calc}


\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

I compile this with `pdflatex -ini -interaction=nonstopmode -save-size=20000 -stack-size=2000 -jobname="packages" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx "packages.tex"`. Here's an MWE of my main file:

```
%&packages

\endofdump

\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{ABABAB}
\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
        fontupper=\normalsize\itshape,
        top=0mm,
        bottom=0mm,
        right=0mm,
        colback=white,
        colframe=black,
        colbacktitle=mygray,
        coltitle=black,
        boxrule=0.05mm,
        titlerule style=white,
    }
}
\newtcbtheorem[]{definition}{Definition}{thmbox}{theo}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition*}{Span}{}
The span of a vector \(\overrightarrow{v_{1}},\ \overrightarrow{v_{2}},\ \ldots,\ \overrightarrow{v_{p}}\) is all possible linear combinations of the vector.
\end{definition*}

\end{document}
```

When I run this as I would without the fmt file, it works, but when I use the fmt file, it doesn't work. I'm having trouble interpreting what the issue is.
This is the expected output without using my format file (sorry for the odd coloring, its a transparent window):

[image: Expected output]

Here is the output in my terminal:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=packages)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15>
L3 programming layer <2020/03/25>
==============================================================================
JOB NAME         : "test"
CUSTOMISED FORMAT: "packages"
PRELOADED FILES:
  report.cls    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  import.sty    2020/04/01  v 6.2
 amsmath.sty    2021/10/15 v2.17l AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2021/08/26 v2.02 operator names
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
mathtools.sty    2021/04/12 v1.27 mathematical typesetting tools
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
    calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2021/03/18 v1.4 programming setup (MH)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
arydshln.sty    2019/02/21 v1.76 
      bm.sty    2021/04/25 v1.2e Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
boldline.sty    2008/02/04 v0.2 Adjust line width in tables
   array.sty    2021/10/04 v2.5f Tabular extension package (FMi)
bookmark.sty    2020-11-06 v1.29 PDF bookmarks (HO)
hyperref.sty    2021-02-27 v7.00k Hypertext links for LaTeX
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref-langpatches.def    2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref: patches for babel langu
ages
 intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
   puenc.def    2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
atbegshi-ltx.sty    2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
 hpdftex.def    2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
atveryend-ltx.sty    2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend packa
ge
with kernel methods
rerunfilecheck.sty    2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
bkm-pdftex.def    2020-11-06 v1.29 bookmark driver for pdfTeX (HO)
booktabs.sty    2020/01/12 v1.61803398 Publication quality tables
csquotes.sty    2021-02-22 v5.2l context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
csquotes.def    2021-02-22 v5.2l csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
csquotes.cfg    
ragged2e.sty    2021/02/05 v3.0 ragged2e Package
footmisc.sty    2011/06/06 v5.5b a miscellany of footnote facilities
  xcolor.sty    2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
dvipsnam.def    2016/06/17 v3.0m Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
  empheq.sty    2017/03/31 v2.15 Emphasizing equations
emptypage.sty    2010/05/30 v1.2 Suppress page numbers and headings on empty pa
ges
endnotes.sty    2020-01-02 endnotes package
enumitem.sty    2019/06/20 v3.9 Customized lists
   esint.sty    
adjustbox.sty    2020/08/19 v1.3 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)
 xkeyval.sty    2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
 adjcalc.sty    2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back-
ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
trimclip.sty    2020/08/19 v1.2 Trim and clip general TeX material
graphicx.sty    2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
collectbox.sty    2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
tc-pdftex.def    2019/01/04 v2.2 Clipping driver for pdftex
ifoddpage.sty    2016/04/23 v1.1 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
 gensymb.sty    2003/07/02 v1.0 (WaS)
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
indentfirst.sty    1995/11/23 v1.03 Indent first paragraph (DPC)
  lipsum.sty    2021-03-03 v2.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
   expl3.sty    2021-11-12 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdftex.def    2021-10-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
  xparse.sty    2021-11-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
  lipsum.ltd
listings.sty    2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2020/03/24 1.8d listings configuration
  cancel.sty    2013/04/12 v2.2 Cancel math terms
marginnote.sty    2018/08/09 v1.4b non floating margin notes for LaTeX
mathrsfs.sty    1996/01/01 Math RSFS package v1.0 (jk)
multirow.sty    2021/03/15 v2.8 Span multiple rows of a table
 nomencl.sty    2021/11/10 v5.6 Nomenclature package
  ifthen.sty    2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
tocbasic.sty    2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
 scrbase.sty    2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
scrlfile.sty    2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)
scrlfile-hook.sty    2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)
 scrlogo.sty    2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (logo)
ntheorem.sty    2011/08/15 1.33
 parskip.sty    2021-03-14 v2.0h non-zero parskip adjustments
     pgf.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  pgfrcs.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  pgfsys.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfplots.sty    2020/02/29 v1.17 Data Visualization (1.17)
    tikz.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  pgffor.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
 savesym.sty    2013/09/02 v1.2 Saves and restores symbols (JG)
 silence.sty    2012/07/02 v1.5b Selective filtering of warnings and error mess
ages
 siunitx.sty    2021/03/27 v2.8c A comprehensive (SI) units package
l3keys2e.sty    2021-11-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
translator.sty    2020-08-03 v1.12c Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
stackengine.sty    2021/07/22 v4.11\ Stacking text and objects in convenient wa
ys
listofitems.sty    2019/08/21 v1.63 Grab items in lists using user-specified se
p char (CT)
stmaryrd.sty    1994/03/03 St Mary's Road symbol package
subcaption.sty    2020/10/07 v1.3j Sub-captions (AR)
 caption.sty    2020/10/26 v3.5g Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2020/10/21 v2.2e caption3 kernel (AR)
subfiles.sty    2020/11/14 v2.2 Multi-file projects (package)
 systeme.sty    2020/05/03 v0.34 Mise en forme de systemes d'equations (CT)
 xstring.sty    2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
tcolorbox.sty    2020/10/09 version 4.42 text color boxes
verbatim.sty    2020-07-07 v1.5u LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
 environ.sty    2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments
trimspaces.sty    2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
  pdfcol.sty    2019/12/29 v1.6 Handle new color stacks for pdfTeX (HO)
shellesc.sty    2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
listingsutf8.sty    2019-12-10 v1.5 Allow UTF-8 in listings input (HO)
stringenc.sty    2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
textcomp.sty    2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
titlesec.sty    2021/07/05 v2.14 Sectioning titles
 tocloft.sty    2017/08/31 v2.3i parameterised ToC, etc., typesetting
todonotes.sty    2018/11/22
transparent.sty    2019/11/29 v1.4 Transparency via pdfTeX's color stack (HO)
 wrapfig.sty    2003/01/31  v 3.6
 xifthen.sty    2015/11/05 v1.4.0 Extended ifthen features
 ifmtarg.sty    2018/04/16 v1.2b check for an empty argument
  xpatch.sty    2020/03/25 v0.3a Extending etoolbox patching commands
  xspace.sty    2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
  uesint.fd    
   ursfs.fd    1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)
  ustmry.fd

==============================================================================
(mylatexformat)Info: start reading document "test"
(mylatexformat)      on input line 3. (\endofdump)
==============================================================================
(/home/username/.latexpreamble/testpreamble.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `/home/username/.latexpreamble/testp
reamble',
               but the package provides `testpreamble'.

(/home/username/.latexpreamble/contents/packages.tex))
No file test.aux.
(/home/username/texmf/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/home/username/texmf/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...}}[]}\fi \@tempa }\fi \dth@everypar 
                                                  ={\@minipagefalse \global ...
l.38 \begin{document}
                     
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
```

If it helps here is my full log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=packages 2021.11.21)  21 NOV 2021 09:26
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15>
L3 programming layer <2020/03/25>
==============================================================================
JOB NAME         : "test"
CUSTOMISED FORMAT: "packages"
PRELOADED FILES:
  report.cls    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  import.sty    2020/04/01  v 6.2
 amsmath.sty    2021/10/15 v2.17l AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2021/08/26 v2.02 operator names
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
mathtools.sty    2021/04/12 v1.27 mathematical typesetting tools
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
    calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2021/03/18 v1.4 programming setup (MH)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
arydshln.sty    2019/02/21 v1.76 
      bm.sty    2021/04/25 v1.2e Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
boldline.sty    2008/02/04 v0.2 Adjust line width in tables
   array.sty    2021/10/04 v2.5f Tabular extension package (FMi)
bookmark.sty    2020-11-06 v1.29 PDF bookmarks (HO)
hyperref.sty    2021-02-27 v7.00k Hypertext links for LaTeX
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref-langpatches.def    2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref: patches for babel langu
ages
 intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
   puenc.def    2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
atbegshi-ltx.sty    2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
 hpdftex.def    2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
atveryend-ltx.sty    2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend packa
ge
with kernel methods
rerunfilecheck.sty    2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
bkm-pdftex.def    2020-11-06 v1.29 bookmark driver for pdfTeX (HO)
booktabs.sty    2020/01/12 v1.61803398 Publication quality tables
csquotes.sty    2021-02-22 v5.2l context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
csquotes.def    2021-02-22 v5.2l csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
csquotes.cfg    
ragged2e.sty    2021/02/05 v3.0 ragged2e Package
footmisc.sty    2011/06/06 v5.5b a miscellany of footnote facilities
  xcolor.sty    2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
dvipsnam.def    2016/06/17 v3.0m Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
  empheq.sty    2017/03/31 v2.15 Emphasizing equations
emptypage.sty    2010/05/30 v1.2 Suppress page numbers and headings on empty pa
ges
endnotes.sty    2020-01-02 endnotes package
enumitem.sty    2019/06/20 v3.9 Customized lists
   esint.sty    
adjustbox.sty    2020/08/19 v1.3 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)
 xkeyval.sty    2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
 adjcalc.sty    2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back-
ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
trimclip.sty    2020/08/19 v1.2 Trim and clip general TeX material
graphicx.sty    2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
collectbox.sty    2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
tc-pdftex.def    2019/01/04 v2.2 Clipping driver for pdftex
ifoddpage.sty    2016/04/23 v1.1 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
 gensymb.sty    2003/07/02 v1.0 (WaS)
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
indentfirst.sty    1995/11/23 v1.03 Indent first paragraph (DPC)
  lipsum.sty    2021-03-03 v2.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
   expl3.sty    2021-11-12 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdftex.def    2021-10-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
  xparse.sty    2021-11-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
  lipsum.ltd
listings.sty    2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2020/03/24 1.8d listings configuration
  cancel.sty    2013/04/12 v2.2 Cancel math terms
marginnote.sty    2018/08/09 v1.4b non floating margin notes for LaTeX
mathrsfs.sty    1996/01/01 Math RSFS package v1.0 (jk)
multirow.sty    2021/03/15 v2.8 Span multiple rows of a table
 nomencl.sty    2021/11/10 v5.6 Nomenclature package
  ifthen.sty    2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
tocbasic.sty    2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
 scrbase.sty    2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
scrlfile.sty    2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)
scrlfile-hook.sty    2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)
 scrlogo.sty    2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (logo)
ntheorem.sty    2011/08/15 1.33
 parskip.sty    2021-03-14 v2.0h non-zero parskip adjustments
     pgf.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  pgfrcs.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  pgfsys.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfplots.sty    2020/02/29 v1.17 Data Visualization (1.17)
    tikz.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  pgffor.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
 savesym.sty    2013/09/02 v1.2 Saves and restores symbols (JG)
 silence.sty    2012/07/02 v1.5b Selective filtering of warnings and error mess
ages
 siunitx.sty    2021/03/27 v2.8c A comprehensive (SI) units package
l3keys2e.sty    2021-11-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
translator.sty    2020-08-03 v1.12c Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
stackengine.sty    2021/07/22 v4.11\ Stacking text and objects in convenient wa
ys
listofitems.sty    2019/08/21 v1.63 Grab items in lists using user-specified se
p char (CT)
stmaryrd.sty    1994/03/03 St Mary's Road symbol package
subcaption.sty    2020/10/07 v1.3j Sub-captions (AR)
 caption.sty    2020/10/26 v3.5g Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2020/10/21 v2.2e caption3 kernel (AR)
subfiles.sty    2020/11/14 v2.2 Multi-file projects (package)
 systeme.sty    2020/05/03 v0.34 Mise en forme de systemes d'equations (CT)
 xstring.sty    2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
tcolorbox.sty    2020/10/09 version 4.42 text color boxes
verbatim.sty    2020-07-07 v1.5u LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
 environ.sty    2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments
trimspaces.sty    2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
  pdfcol.sty    2019/12/29 v1.6 Handle new color stacks for pdfTeX (HO)
shellesc.sty    2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
listingsutf8.sty    2019-12-10 v1.5 Allow UTF-8 in listings input (HO)
stringenc.sty    2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
textcomp.sty    2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
titlesec.sty    2021/07/05 v2.14 Sectioning titles
 tocloft.sty    2017/08/31 v2.3i parameterised ToC, etc., typesetting
todonotes.sty    2018/11/22
transparent.sty    2019/11/29 v1.4 Transparency via pdfTeX's color stack (HO)
 wrapfig.sty    2003/01/31  v 3.6
 xifthen.sty    2015/11/05 v1.4.0 Extended ifthen features
 ifmtarg.sty    2018/04/16 v1.2b check for an empty argument
  xpatch.sty    2020/03/25 v0.3a Extending etoolbox patching commands
  xspace.sty    2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
  uesint.fd    
   ursfs.fd    1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)
  ustmry.fd

==============================================================================
(mylatexformat)Info: start reading document "test"
(mylatexformat)      on input line 3. (\endofdump)
==============================================================================
(/home/username/.latexpreamble/testpreamble.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `/home/username/.latexpreamble/testp
reamble',
               but the package provides `testpreamble'.

Package: testpreamble 
(/home/username/.latexpreamble/contents/packages.tex))
\c@tcb@cnt@definition=\count409
Package csquotes Info: Checking for multilingual support...
Package csquotes Info: ... none found.

No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 38.
(/home/username/texmf/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2021-04-02 v2.47 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/home/username/texmf/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count410
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 38.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 38.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 38.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...}}[]}\fi \@tempa }\fi \dth@everypar 
                                                  ={\@minipagefalse \global ...
l.38 \begin{document}
                      
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 353 strings out of 429134
 8124 string characters out of 4708361
 1680581 words of memory out of 5000000
 66796 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 412885 words of font info for 64 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 74i,1n,92p,369b,53s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I would really appreciate any help I can get with this. Thanks for reading!
**Edit:**
Everything has been updated after I initially compiled my file without loading ntheorem.

Comment: Well I think that you should at first spent some time to clean up your preamble.  You load various packages more then once, and also packages which offer similar  functions like e.g. mdframed and tcolorbox.

Comment: From the first error `! Undefined control sequence. l.8 \newtheoremstyle` and your input `\newmdtheoremenv[...,ntheorem]{definition}{Definition}`, you didn't load `ntheorem` package. The `mdframe` package manual reads "ntheorem  Before setting this boolean key, you have to load the package `ntheorem`."

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I looked through my packages file and didn't see any duplicates, which ones are loaded multiple times? Thanks for the suggestion with mdframed and tcolorbox, I've migrated all references of mdframed to tcb. Unfortunately it didn't help with the problem.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ My apologies, I rushed the creation of my MWE and I forgot that I had moved `\usepackage{ntheorem}` to my main file. I'll update my question now. I also reduced my MWE as suggested by @Ulrike Fischer

Comment: Well I see at least xcolor and mathtools. Xparse, textcomp are unneeded, import and subfiles do similar things, url is loaded by hyperref etc. Sorry but your preamble is quite a mess.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the advice, I've kept the same preamble for all my projects since I first started LaTeX when I was just copying anything off of overleaf's guide or stack exchange so there I'm not surprised that there's stuff I don't need. I'll be sure to clean it up.

Comment: Well do it. I don't feel much inclined to debug a problem with a messy preamble. Even more if there are doubts that your mwe actually reproduces the problem. Your error message says something a `testpreamble.sty` which can be seen nowhere.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your help,I organized my preamble and as I was doing so, I discovered that there were to packages that caused issues: the bookmark package and stmaryrd were causing separate problems. Once I removed them, it worked with no errors.  I have no idea whats wrong with them but I don't need them so I'll mark this as solved